# Difference between two solutions for a for loop problem?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem in software called MyProgrammingLab that is used for teaching in my python class. The question is:

An arithmetic progression is a sequence of numbers in which the distance (or difference) between any two successive numbers if the same. This in the sequence 1, 3, 5, 7, ..., the distance is 2 while in the sequence 6, 12, 18, 24, ..., the distance is 6.

Given the positive integer distance and the positive integer n, associate the variable sum with the sum of the elements of the arithmetic progression from 1 to n with distance "distance". For example, if distance is 2 and n is 10, then sum would be associated with 25 because 1+3+5+7+9 = 25.

My solution was:

```
sum = 0
for n in range(1,n+1,distance):
    sum += n
```

If I use 10 for example for n, I am getting the right answer 25 but this solution is not being accepted by the software. It saying that the value of n is being modified.

The accepted answer is:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1,n+1,distance):
    sum += i
```

Both solutions are giving the same answers if n = 10 but my first solution is giving an error that the value of n was modified.

My professor said that the mean of n, i, sum should be separate which is not in my solution. To demonstrate he said to print out value of n:

```
sum = 0
n = 10
distance = 2
for n in range(1,n+1,distance):
    print(n)
```

The result is 1,3,5,7 and 9 (original n value of 10 is being changed)

Using the accepted solution:

```
sum = 0
n = 10
distance = 2
for i in range(1,n+1,distance):
    print(n)
```

Answer is: 10,10,10,10 (the value of n is not change)

So my question is that if both solutions are getting the right answer, what's the significance of value of n changing or not changing ?

Comment: "but my first solution is giving an error that the value of n was modified. " <---- The software checks that `n` is being modified or not, apparently. There is no significance for this problem, but I would consider it bad practice to have a `for n in range(<n in here also>)`

Comment: I'm not sure if i get your question correctly, but in general you should only use variable names in loops like that, if you don't use them in the rest of your code. So if you use `n` outside of your loop it's better to loop over `i` and vice versa.

Comment: Seems like a problem with the environment in which you are programming. A regular python shell would not complain about this

Comment: @smac89 Yeah, the python shell doesn't complain about it but apparently it's not the right way to approach the problem.

Comment: @Quastiat - Yes, I think that is the issue here. It's a bad practice to do that.

Comment: I just find it ironic that it complains about `n` being overwritten, but it tells you to declare a variable called `sum` which shadows the python builtin `sum` function and doesn't complain about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you generally want to avoid re-using variable names. There are a ton of caveats -- for example, in many cases its useful to have multiple functions that use the same name for the input arg to imply similarity on what the inputs across the functions should be -- but it's a good rule of thumb.

With that in mind, take a look at your solution:

```
sum = 0
for n in range(1,n+1,distance):
    sum += n
```

While the number `n` has been set as 10 (I assume that it's set earlier in the program with a line of `n=10`? Or maybe it's already in the namespace because of the "MyProgrammingLab" software?), you are then going on to re-use the name `n` as the variable being incremented in the for-loop. The software is (sorta) correct in saying the value of `n` is being modified. With every step the for-loop goes, you are assigning a new value to `n`. The first run of loop, `n` is 1. The next run of the loop, `n` is (1+distance), etc. So `n` is being repeatedly re-assigned.

This causes confusion for what `n` represents: does it mean how many numbers are being added together? Or is it the current value in *this* run of the for-loop? To avoid that, it's better to just use an entirely different value for the variable being incremented as the for-loop processes. The official solution uses `i`, that's fine. You could also say something like `current_value`, or whatever you find makes it easier to remember what its meaning in that moment is.